# How to use the word 'investigate'

Tags: word-usage

I want to express something like 'I dig further into Quantum Mechanics',which of the following is correct?

> 1). investigate further into quantum mechanics
>
> 2). do a further investigation **on** quantum mechanics
>
> 3). carry out a further investigation **on** quantum mechanics
>
> 4). do a further investigation **into** quantum mechanics
>
> 5). carry out a further investigation **into** quantum mechanics

Is there any alternative expression that I can use? I want to use as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> ...do [or make] a deeper study of Quantum Mechanics.

"Investigation" sounds more like you're looking into a situation that isn't clear (like a detective would), whereas if you're trying to deepen your knowledge of a well-known field, "study" might be more appropriate.

Comment: Shall I use 'study of Quantum Mechanics' or 'on Quanum Mechanics' or 'into Quantum Mechanics'?

Comment: "study of Quantum Mechanics" sounds best